# if and else condition in select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want a query in which if and else will use but I do not know how it will use,below is my table structure ,i want result below mentioned after Produce table.

> Item Master Table

```
item_code    Item_Name   Weight     UOM 
  1001         Pen        44       unit 
  1002       Computer     42       unit
```

Customer Table

```
Customer_ID  Customer_Name   Contact    Address
     1             Akhter         3434       3434
     2             Hussain        333        555
```

Customer Item Table

```
Customer_ItemCode    Customer_ItemName   Item_code(FK)  Weight  Customer_ID(FK) 
 2001                    Pen America          1           100       1
```

SalesOrder Table

```
Order_No     Customer_ID (FK)   Order_Ref   Date     
     1           1                 333       333     
     2           2                 222       222
```

Produce table

```
Prod_No Item_Code(FK)    qty    Order_No (FK)
   10001     1            1         1    
   10002     2            1          2
```

when select 10001 record from Produce table then it result like
`(10001,Pen America,1)`
when i select record 10002 then it result like 
`(10002,Computer,1)`

Comment: Please post the DDLs (`create table`)  statements and a few `INSERT` statements.  Most importantly, I would like to see the Constraints (FKs, PKs, etc.)

Comment: You would be better posting what you are trying to achieve, rather than saying you want to use IF/ELSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic query is pretty straight forward:

```
SELECT p.Prod_No,
    IsNull(Customer_ItemName, i.Item_Name) as Item_Name,
    p.qty
FROM Produce p
INNER JOIN ItemMaster I
    ON p.item_code = i.item_code
INNER JOIN SalesOrder s
    ON s.Order_No = p.Order_No
LEFT JOIN CustomerItem ci
    ON p.item_code = ci.item_code
```

This makes some assumptions about your data, such as the fact that there is no item with an item_code of **1**, as shown in the Produce table (Probably should be the Product table?  Or is this Order_items or something similar). In any case, I'm assuming that 1 = 1001, and 2 = 1002

Comment: #Laughing Vergil, you didn't make check customer in customer item table,that if item name is define against customer then that item name will be select from customer item file ,if does not mentioned customer in customer item file against item then item will be select from item master file ,